# curves based hair system not working as expected

Tags: hair

Following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0BZl8woduU I tried out the new curves based hair system (I'm on Blender 3.6). In the tutorial every thing works (mirroring, collision, etc.) but I'm in an alternate reality. What am I doing wrong?

Here are some examples:

Mirroring on X would come and go, then on the top of the head, no matter what I did I couldn't get rid of the bald spot:

[image: bald spot]

Collision was also spotty. Here are some examples of the hair going through the character's body:

[image: hair goes thru ears]
[image: hair goes thru shoulder]

I turned off mirroring and trimmed the bangs in the front of the head and, weirdly,the hair on the back of the head got trimmed as well:

[image: zzz]

I'm fairly new at Blender, maybe I'm missing something obvious? Any advice would be appreciated.

Thx, M.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: About trimming the bangs: Set the brush falloff to *Sphere* instead of *Projected*. The setting is the 2 buttons in the viewport's toolbar. It changes the way the brush works. When *Sphere* is enabled, the mouse cursor acts as a 3D sphere and only the hair curves inside are affected. So you need to point & click at the hair curves that you want to cut or comb. *Projected* on the other hand, creates a line from your point of view to the cursor and affects everthing in that line, even if you drag the cursor. This way it cuts the bangs and the hair on the back of the head at the same time.

Comment: About the bald spot: either the hair curves are inside of the head. Or there is something wrong with *Surface Deform* modifier. Are there any errors? Have you created a haircap or do you use the head of the model as surface object? If latter, are there any modifiers on the model? -- About collision/clipping: this is a common problem. Even if you comb the hair behind the ears, then modifiers (curl, roll, bend, frizz, noise, etc) can still make the hair children go through the ears. I think the only solution is to comb it so it doesn't clip ...?

Comment: Blunder, if you post these as an answer, I will accept it. I do feel you answered me as I have a way to proceed. But, from what I read, I can't accept comments.